# Get User Properties (personal site) without admin permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest, csom

Is possible to get a users personal site information from this endpoint 
`/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getpropertiesfor` or by another means without having admin rights?

I need to be able to get a users personal site (OneDrive for Business Url), when I try with a non admin account I get 403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more testing the following endpoint will work to get the personalSite:
**https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/**_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getpropertiesfor(@v)?@v='i%3a0%23.f%7cmembership%7cuser%40tenant.onmicrosoft.com'

In Office 365 the user is a user non administration access.

This is for SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot use `/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getpropertiesfor` endpoint without admin rights. Please find more details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163182.aspx#bk_Prereqs).

The other method which you can try is using search REST API. In that case you can use people search and get the results. The endpoint will be:

`/_api/search/query?querytext='username'&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'`

Find more details [here](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/01/calling-sharepoint-search-using-rest-eg.html)

Comment: Thanks, from what I can see when I've tested this, the personal site ie https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/username_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/ is not in the results

Comment: True that. PersonImmersive is there.